# Lean complains it can't see that a statement is decidable

Tags: decidable, lean

I'm trying to define the following quantity partn:

```
variable pi : nat -> Prop
variable (Hdecp : ∀ p, decidable (pi p))

definition partn (n : nat) : nat := ∏ p ∈ (prime_factors n), (if pi p then p^(mult p n) else 1)
```

but get the error

```
error: failed to synthesize placeholder
pi : ℕ → Prop,
n p : ℕ
⊢ decidable (pi p)
```

How can I help Lean recognize that (pi p) is indeed decidable thanks to Hdecp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**edit**: The elaborator can actually infer the instance completely on its own, as long it's available in the definition's context:

```
variable (Hdecp : ∀ p, decidable (pi p))

include Hdecp
definition partn (n : nat) : nat := ∏ p ∈ (prime_factors n), (if pi p then p^(mult p n) else 1)
```

---

original answer (still useful if the instance has more complex hypotheses):

If you want to avoid the explicit call to `ite`, you can locally introduce the `decidable` instance:

```
definition partn (n : nat) : nat := ∏ p ∈ (prime_factors n),
have decidable (pi p), from Hdecp p,
if pi p then p^(mult p n) else 1
```

Comment: There's actually an even simpler solution, I've edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
definition partn (n : nat) : nat := ∏ p ∈ (prime_factors n), (@ite (pi p) (Hdecp p) nat (p^(mult p n)) 1)
```

which allows me to explicitly use Hdecp in my if-the-else